# Convert the following Riccati equation into an LMI

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, linear-matrix-inequality

I need help to convert the following discrete-time Riccati eqn. into an LMI with two decision variables $(K, P)$:

$$ (A+BK)^T P (A+BK) - P +Q + K^T R K \prec 0$$

The trick, at least for the continuous-time variant [here](https://yalmip.github.io/example/lpvstatefeedback/), seems to be with a congruence transformation, i.e., multiply both LHS and RHS of the above by $Y = P^{-1}$, then, define $L = KY$ and apply Schur. I did the first two pieces, but, wasn't able to do the Schur part. ([This](http://maecourses.ucsd.edu/~mdeolive/mae280b/lecture/lecture8.pdf) also seems to be a useful reference)

Also, as I do not have the control systems toolbox for Matlab, can someone provide me (or point me) with (to) a Matlab implementation for solving the DARE eqn, i.e., the second eqn. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_Riccati_equation)?

Answer (score 4):

You have $Y - YQY - (AY + BL)^TY^{-1}(AY+BL) - L^TRL \succeq 0$.

Apply Schur three times, or see it as $$Y  - \begin{bmatrix}AY + BL\\L\\Y\end{bmatrix}^T\begin{bmatrix}Y  & 0 &0\\ 0 & R^{-1} & 0 \\0 & 0 & Q^{-1}\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}AY + BL\\L\\Y\end{bmatrix}\succeq 0$$

and apply Schur once